# I am getting this error while creating a new flutter project in android studio related to pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, yaml

name: i_am_poor
description: A new Flutter project.

publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
sdk: ">=2.16.2 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
flutter:
sdk: flutter

cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2

dev_dependencies:
flutter_test:
sdk: flutter

flutter_lints: ^1.0.0

flutter:

uses-material-design: true

assets:
- images/

Error on line 33, column 10 of pubspec.yaml: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
â•·
33 â”‚    assets:
â”‚          ^
â•µ
Process finished with exit code 65

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of pubspec.yaml ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thats issue with pubspec.yaml file which ahs no proper formatting.Please see atatched how pubspecs.yaml file looks. You need to follow indent and specing for pubspec file format as it self explanatory.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In screenshots , you can see that how the proper spacing works.